# How to parse a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm just curious how I go about splitting a variable into a few other variables.

For example, say I have the following JavaScript:

```
var coolVar = '123-abc-itchy-knee';
```

And I wanted to split that into 4 variables, how does one do that?

To wind up with an array where

```
array[0] == 123
and
array[1] == abc
```

etc would be cool.

Or (a variable for each part of the string)

```
var1 == 123  
and 
var2 == abc
```

Could work... either way. How do you split a JavaScript string?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use the Javascript string split() function.

```
var coolVar = '123-abc-itchy-knee';
var partsArray = coolVar.split('-');

// Will result in partsArray[0] == '123', partsArray[1] == 'abc', etc
```

Comment: coool, awesome, brilliant )

Comment: If you put something else in `coolVar` be sure to add `coolVar.toString().split('-')` if you get an exception.

Answer (score 19):

Use split on string:

```
var array = coolVar.split(/-/);
```

Comment: Does split take regexes? I thought it just took a search string.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a constant regex, it can be more complex. For example: `"hello-there_stranger".split(/-|_/)` returns a 3-element array.

Answer (score 3):

as amber and sinan have noted above, the javascritp '.split' method will work just fine. Just pass it the string separator(-) and the string that you intend to split('123-abc-itchy-knee') and it will do the rest.

```
    var coolVar = '123-abc-itchy-knee';
    var coolVarParts = coolVar.split('-'); // this is an array containing the items

    var1=coolVarParts[0]; //this will retrieve 123
```

To access each item from the array just use the respective index(indices start at zero).