# Extract substring out of a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

All,

I have the following html as a string in javascript. I need to extract the string in "value", split by the specified delimeter "|" and put in two variables.

```
var html = '<div><input name="radBtn" class="radClass" style="margin:auto;" 
       onclick="doSomething();"
       value="Apples|4567" type="radio">
</div>';
```

Required output is two variables having the following values:

```
fruitName = Apples
fruitNumber = 4567
```

Note: There can be many radio buttons with the same name.

Comment: Everyone answering in this thread is not reading the problem. It's not HTML, it's a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can assume that your HTML is always going to be simple (i.e. only one value attribute, and nothing else that looks like a value attribute), then you can do something like this:

```
var fruit = html.match(/value="(.*?)\|(.*?)"/);
if (fruit) {
    fruitName = fruit[1];
    fruitValue = fruit[2];
}
```

Comment: I really need to become more competent with regex. :/

Comment: @Vincent I added an extra `?` to my regex just in case there's another `|` in the string somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it:

```
$("input[name='radBtn']").click(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    val = val.split("|");

    var fruit = val[0];
    var number = val[1];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<input name="radBtn" class="radClass" style="margin:auto;" onclick="doSomething();" value="Apples|4567" type="radio"></div>';  

var str = div.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].split("|");

var fruitName = str[0];
var fruitNumber = str[1];

/*
Now,
fruitName = "Apples"
and
fruitNumber = 4567
*/
```

Comment: I think you're looking to call split on the defaultValue property or value attribute rather than on the input element itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
var fruit = (function() {
    var fruits = $(html).find('.radClass').val().split('|');
    return {
        fruitName: fruits[0],
        fruitNumber: fruits[1]
    };
}());
```

You'll get an object like this:

```
fruit.fruitName // Apples
fruit.fruitNumber // 4567
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var coolVar = '123-abc-itchy-knee';
var partsArray = coolVar.split('-');

// Will result in partsArray[0] == '123', partsArray[1] == 'abc', etc
```

see: [How to parse a string in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216505/how-do-i-parse-a-string-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: how do i get the value from the html string first?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("INPUT[name=radBtn]").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val().split("|");
        var fruitName = value[0];
        var fruitNumber = value[1];

        // Add to an array, ajax post etc. whatever you want to do with the data here
    });
});
```

Comment: i can't click on the radio button.. its in an html string.. please see the question again.. thanks

Comment: Ah I see, you want to get the values from the string before you append to the DOM. May I ask why?