# How to extract a string from url using javascript

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I have following string:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/ABC"> </a>
```

How can I extract text (i.e.ABC) from the string?

Comment: Kindly post your code then only we can help you.

Comment: here is my code <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/ABC"> </a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract substring out of a string using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810431/extract-substring-out-of-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `anchorObject.pathname` or `anchorObject.href.match(/\/([^/]+)$/)[1]` if you just want the last path.
You still need to get the anchorObject from the DOM.

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const elm = parser.parseFromString('<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/posts"></a>', 'text/html');
const anchorObject = elm.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

And voilà.

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to fetch the string
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[19].innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure of what the length of the variable you're looking for is, you can use this syntax.

```
let string = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/ABC"> </a>';
console.log(string.split('"')[1].split('/')[3]);
```

If you know what you're looking for ( for Example: ABC ) you can find index of ABC, and splice the string.

```
let variable = 'ABC'
console.log(string.substr(string.search("ABC"), variable.length))
```

Breakdown the string until you get the variable.