# Trying to asynchronously load data from file on server. Webhost pollutes echoed data and AJAX function returns undefined when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, asynchronous

I have this code:

```
    var temp = getLevel(0);
    console.log("outside" + temp + "/outside");

    function getLevel(level) {
        var httpRequest, lvlCode;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); // most browsers
        if (window.ActiveXObject) httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE8 and older
        httpRequest.open('GET', 'get-level.php', true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                lvlCode = httpRequest.responseText;
                console.log("inside" + lvlCode + "/inside");
                return lvlCode; 
            }
        };
        httpRequest.send("lvl=" + level);
    }
```

Console returns:

```
outsideundefinedoutside (index):111
inside<data I want>
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
/inside
```

There are two issues here: first, Hosting24 pollutes my echoed data. How do I get rid of the Hosting24 text? Second, why is `temp` undefined when it should contain exactly the same as lvlCode?

Comment: "*How do I get rid of the Hosting24 text?*" -- By finding a better hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get rid of the Hosting24 text?

You'd have to parse it out manually.  (Or, as mentioned in a comment on the question, use a host which doesn't inject content into your site.)  String parsing can often be an inexact science.  You might start with something simple like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216505/how-to-parse-a-string-in-javascript), or something more complex like [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).  (Though [HTML parsing with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/328193) is also a *very* inexact science.)

---

> Second, why is temp undefined when it should contain exactly the same as lvlCode?

The [question linked in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) says it all.  (It's kind of a half-duplicate, since you're asking two questions.)  Essentially, look at what you're doing:

```
var temp = getLevel(0);
```

However, the `getLevel` function *doesn't return anything*.  Since nothing is returned, naturally `temp` is going to be undefined.  An *entirely different* function, used as an anonymous callback function to the asynchronous AJAX call, returns something.  But where does that return value go?  `getLevel()` finishes executing and returns nothing long before that AJAX call completes.  (Hence, "asynchronous")

You don't want to *return* values from asynchronous callback functions.  Instead, you want to perform your actions in response to those callbacks.

So instead of this:

```
var temp = getLevel(0);
console.log("outside" + temp + "/outside");

function getLevel(level) {
    //...
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //...
        return lvlCode;
    }
    //...
}
```

Do this:

```
getLevel(0);

function getLevel(level) {
    //...
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //...
        console.log("outside" + temp + "/outside");
    }
    //...
}
```